# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'loginState.isLoading')

Tags: react-native, typeerror, asyncstorage

I am trying to authenticate a login using Async Storage with React Native. Every time I click on the SignUp button in my simulator it throws me a type error saying "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'loginState.isLoading')". I believe the problem is how I'm defining loginState. Here is the page where I define loginState below:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Component, Text,TouchableWithoutFeedback, View,Image,SafeAreaView, Button, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


import MainTabScreen from './screens/MainTab';
import {DrawerContent} from './screens/DrawerContent';
import RootStackScreen from './screens/RootStack'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
//import { firebaseConfig } from './screens/config';
import { AuthContext } from './components/context';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

 

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function App() {
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  // const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null); 

  const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: true,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null,
  };

  const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGIN': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGOUT': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
    }
  };

  const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
    signIn: (userName,password) =>{
      // setUserToken('tony');
      // setIsLoading(false);
      let userToken;
      userToken = null;
      if (userName == 'user' && password == 'pass'){
        userToken = 'lexi';
      }
      dispatch({type:'LOGIN,',id:userName, token:userToken});
    },
    signOut: () => {
      // setUserToken(null);
      // setIsLoading(false);
      dispatch({type:'LOGOUT'});
    },
    signUp: () => {
      setUserToken('tony');
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
  }),[])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     // setIsLoading(false);
     dispatch({type:'RETRIEVE_TOKEN',token:'mario'});
    },1000);
  },[]);


  if (loginState.isLoading == true)
  {
    return(
      <View style = {{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size = "large"/>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value = {authContext}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loginState.userToken !== null ? (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent = {props => <DrawerContent {... props}/>}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={MainTabScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator> 
      )
      :
        <RootStackScreen/>
      }
    </NavigationContainer> 
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I changed:

```
  dispatch({type:'LOGIN,',id:userName, token:userToken});
```

To:

```
  dispatch({type:'LOGIN',id:userName, token:userToken});
```